# TYPO3: get path out of file reference in Extbase

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

i've created a Custom Content Element with Fluid and Extbase (TYPO3 6.1), in which you can define a picture. 
In the picture-settings i can set a img-link, which is targetting a file.

In my Controller i can access this data with

```
$this->configurationManager->getContentObject();
```

But i just get a file-reference for this setting and no path. like this:

```
file:1206
```

I've googled a lot and i didn't find a solution to access the path. Has anybody a solution or knows maybe a function in the configurationmanager or something else? I've spend hours on this problem...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is it possible that you have the `FAL` (file abstraction layer) extension enabled?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you have there, is a file reference of `FAL`, the file abstraction layer.

First things first, if you use FlexForms in combination with ActionController (or any realisation of [AbstractController](http://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_mvc_1_1_controller_1_1_abstract_controller.html)) you should be able to access the `settings` property to compute your FlexForm values.

To compute `sys_file_reference` records, you should refer to the [FAL docs on typo3.org](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Fal/Index.html) (and the perma-linked [section about file and folder handling](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Fal/UsingFal/ExamplesFileFolder.html)).

In general, you should be able to call `getOriginalResource()` on a `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference` object. For more concrete examples, either refer to the doc links or have a look at [the wiki](http://wiki.typo3.org/File_Abstraction_Layer) for a example handling FileReferences.

If you want to compute such reference via fluid templating, you can use the `treatIdAsReference` argument on f:image:

`<f:image src="{imageObj.uid}" width="150" height="100" treatIdAsReference="1" />`

Comment: I would recommend using the provided `image` property, instead of parsing the uid through the src attribute. So `<f:image image="{imageObj}" treatIdAsReference="TRUE" />`

Answer (score 15):

If you need to get image from FAL than use following image view helper

```
<f:image src="{object.image_field.uid}" alt="{object.image_field.originalResource.title}" width="640" height="291" treatIdAsReference="1" />
```

If you just need url of image than use following line

{object.image.originalResource.publicUrl}..

Hurray.

Answer (score 3):

He is asking for a path and not for an image. This prints the path in fluid templates:

```
{f:uri.image(src:'{object.uid}',treatIdAsReference:'1')}
```

Comment: Thats what he is asking for, but not, what he is actually trying to achive. People are like that sometimes.

Comment: @j4k3 Sure ... me too. But the google search is stupid and just looks for words. Maybe someone will find that page and is looking for what he is asking for and wants to achive exactly what he is asking for in the headline ... like me before I found the answer elserwhere ... than there is no need to look elsewhere :-)