# Get path of FAL media?

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-6.2.x, tx-news

Using Fluid Template with tx_news, I need to get the URL of uploaded FAL video.

Currently I have this:

```
{newsItem.falMedia.0}
```

Which prints:

```
GeorgRinger\News\Domain\Model\FileReference:3
```

I want the output:

```
fileadmin/user_upload/MyVideo.mp4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

newsItem.falMedia seems to be an ObjectStorage. With .0 you are pointing to the first object of it - not any function of it. In the API you can see its functions http://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/current/html/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_core_1_1_resource_1_1_file_reference.html or you can debug it in Fluid by using {newsItem.falMedia.0}

Example: {newsItem.falMedia.0.publicUrl} should give you the public path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need url of image than use following line

{object.image.originalResource.publicUrl}..

[TYPO3: get path out of file reference in Extbase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18210635/typo3-get-path-out-of-file-reference-in-extbase/30798031#30798031)

Please refer above link.